# Middleware type functionality of Laravel in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am new to AngularJS I have been recently deployed to a AngularJS project. Now at backend I use Laravel and I want to know if there is a way in Angular that I can create or use the same functionality what middleware does in Laravel.

What I basically want is that I need if user is logged in then only he can move forward in the application to other pages.

I have tried something but I don't feel it is correct.

```
app.controller('afterLogin', function ($scope, $http, $translate,$state,toastr,$auth) {

    var init = function () {
        var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: baseUrl + 'username',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
            }
        };
        $http(req)
            .then(function (response) {
                if(response.data.name != '')
                {
                    $state.go('app.dashboard');
                }
                else
                {
                    $state.go('core.login');
                }


            });

    };
// and fire it after definition
    init();
    $scope.login = function($Login_form) {
        var req = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: baseUrl + 'login/check',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
            },
            data: $scope.user
        };

        $http(req)
            .then(function (response) {
                if(response.data.status == 'success')
                {
                    $state.go('app.dashboard');
                    toastr.success('', 'Logged in successfully');
                }else
                {
                    toastr.warning('', response.data.message);
                }
            });

    };
```

Now the `init()` does is that it goes to my Laravel controller and checks is user is logged in if not then returns to login page else other wise to dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a common problem, I had to solve it too.

Basically you sohuld use the ui-router and then for the states where authentication is needed, you can call an authentication function to proof if the user is logged or not (I also check if it has the roles a to access).

I suggest the use of a service to store the User state.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  //
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to /home
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
  //
  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
      controller: 'homeController',
      controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .state('contact', {
      url: "/contact",
      templateUrl: "partials/contact.html",
      controller: 'contactController',
      controllerAs: 'contactCtrl'
    })

     .state('profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'partials/profile.html',
        controller: 'profileCtrl',
        resolve: {
            authenticated: authentic
        }
    });


     function authentic($q, $location, $auth) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (!$auth.isAuthenticated()) {
            $location.path('/login');
        } else {
            deferred.resolve();
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});
```

I hope it helps.